# Can't get fixed size of workspace switcher on Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, workspaces, gnome-shell-extension, workspace-switcher

I just installed workspace-grid gnome extension. I also enabled the grid workspace in gnome. The only problem I get is why I can't see the fixed size workspace indicator while switching the workspace? Example shown below:

[image]
[image]

I switch to several workspaces while working. This resizing seems painful to me. Is there any way to fix it? Thanks

Comment: You mean the size difference of the pop-ups?

Comment: yes............

Comment: have you found since how to do it?

Comment: Have you rebooted your system once after installing the extension?

Comment: Sounds like a temporary issue which may appear just after installing the extension and should be fixed by a reboot (or restarting GNOME shell). There is an [identical question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1121930/480481) asked recently where [OP clarifies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1121930/when-i-move-from-one-view-to-another-my-workspace-switcher-layout-change-size-w#comment1855362_1121930) that the issue disappeared after a reboot.